# iOS: autolayout for multiple button

Tags: ios, layout, uibutton, autolayout, ios-autolayout

In my app I have a view for 4 inch screens in this way:

[image]

And then I want to reduce the size of my buttons when the app is running on an iPhone with a 3.5 inch screen, so I set my layout in this way:

[image]

but finally I obtain a view in this way

[image]

In this way the size of my button are ok but they are not aligned, so in this situation, what's the way to have aligned buttons?

thanks

Comment: show all of your constraints, please

Comment: Add the alignment constraint...

Comment: @NKB what type of alignment should I use?

Comment: Try using AutoResizing Mask for this..it works for me

Comment: @Geet where is this option? I'm using autolayout

Comment: @nazz_areno you can't use autoresizing with autolayout

Comment: @NikitaTook yes I know, so what the solution to my problem?

Comment: Oh…then no, you won't be able to use Autorezizing Mask if you're using autolayout, you may have to uncheck the Use Autolayout option from your storyboard and the on the SIze-Inspector , you would be able to see these options

Comment: no no, I want to use autolayout!!!

Comment: @nazz_areno if you want them to keep same spacing to screen bounds and same spacing between circles you can try set horizontal spacing between circles, and add trailing/leading spacing to circles. Then add same width constraint

Comment: I solve my problem to setting autolayout as I show in my image, but the space to nearest neighbor is different; I set for the sx buttons space only for up, left and down and for dx buttons I set only up right and down... so in this way with the "aspect ratio" and with "equals width and height" I obtain a optimal layout for iphone 3.5 inches... thanks for te suggest

Comment: great answer ... it solved my problem ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi as per your question i've created demo similar to the layout for which you need the controls need to set. I've added images for single control and  made video this using multiple controls to set the layout which you retrying to set.

[image]
[image]

link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nl2iMF0yKW8&list=PLXCowKcXAVgrxHKLWTa4HxNPrSmTj3D-_

Hope this will solve your issue.

Comment: hey thanks man... I already solved this problem.. but I'll se your video to see your suggest, thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 1):

I may not comment till I 50 posts, so here is the link. I had like the same problem some days ago. Just put all those in a parent view and center the parent view.

Link to my question/answer:
[Top constraint won't get less with auto-layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24907935/top-constraint-wont-get-less-with-auto-layout/24908237#24908237)