# Autolayout views always same size on different screen sizes

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, autolayout

I have a view: [image: View]

Can someone help me to layout these views that they all look the same on every iPhone? I mean size is dynamic and views shrink according to screen size.

I have tried aspect ration and other layout options but none helped.

Comment: and how do they look on different screen sizes? should we use our _wild_ and _random_ imagination or you would like to share those shoots as well?

Comment: lots of answers available in stackoverflow. search answer before post new question. i closed you

Answer (score 2):

if you want to change the view sizes on different screens using auto layout ,you have to add the height and width constraints .then only it changes view size.

Steps:

1. open your project in xcode.
2. goto storyboard choose Auto layout ,select your view ,
3. in Xcode From the Editor menu, choose Pin\Width and Height both

   http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1

Answer (score 1):

As per your question please look at the link below it might help solving your problem of multiple views size and layout.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27471120/4101371

you can also refer:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nl2iMF0yKW8&list=PLXCowKcXAVgrxHKLWTa4HxNPrSmTj3D-_

I've also added this link in the answer in above answer.